# How can I change the font-size of a select option?

Tags: css, html-select, font-size

I am trying to style a select option dropdown list. Is it possible to make the font-sizes of the options different from the default value?
For example, the default:

```
-- Select Country --
```

Would be size 7pt; and one of the options,

```
Georgia
```

Would be size 13pt.

This is my dropdown list:

```css
.select_join {
  width: 170px;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://s24.postimg.org/lyhytocf5/dropdown.png') no-repeat right #FEFEFE;
  border: #FEFEFE 1px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px #FEFEFE;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px #FEFEFE;
}
.select_join select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 170px;
  font-size:7pt;
  color:grey;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 28px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.select_join select:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:pink;height:150px; text-align:center;">
  <br/>
  <div class="select_join" style="margin-left:15px">
    <select name="txtCountry">
      <option>-- Select Country --</option>
      <option value="1">Georgia</option>
      <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also my [demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VggvD/50/).

Unfortunately, it works only on Firefox. Could it be that others browser don't support styling of `<option>` elements?

Browsers I tested on:

- Chrome: Version 27.0.1453.116 m
- IE: 10
- Firefox: 22.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a CSS class to the `<option>` tag to style it: [http://jsfiddle.net/Ahreu/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahreu/50/)

Currently WebKit browsers don't support this behavior, as it's undefined by the spec. Take a look at this: [How to style a select tag's option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5887133/2756409)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work on chrome right?

Comment: You're right, google chrome has a strange behaviour on this. Check my updated answer.

Comment: It might not support for font-sizing :(

Comment: Yep, but your solution is work on firefox :) Thank you

Answer (score 19):

### We need a trick here...

Normal select-dropdown things won't accept styles. BUT. If there's a "size" parameter in the tag, almost any CSS will apply. With this in mind, I've created a fiddle that's practically equivalent to a normal select tag, plus the value can be edited manually like a ComboBox in visual languages (unless you put *readonly* in the input tag).

#### A simplified example:

```
<style>

    /* only these 2 lines are truly required */
    .stylish span {position:relative;}
    .stylish select {position:absolute;left:0px;display:none}

    /* now you can style the hell out of them */
    .stylish input    { ... }
    .stylish select   { ... }
    .stylish option   { ... }
    .stylish optgroup { ... }

</style>
...
<div class="stylish">
    <label> Choose your superhero: </label>
    <span>
        <input onclick="$(this).closest('div').find('select').slideToggle(110)">
        <br>
        <select size=15 onclick="$(this).hide().closest('div').find('input').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());">

            <optgroup label="Fantasy"></optgroup>
            <option value="gandalf">Gandalf</option>
            <option value="harry">Harry Potter</option>
            <option value="jon">Jon Snow</option>

            <optgroup label="Comics"></optgroup>
            <option value="tony">Tony Stark</option>
            <option value="steve">Steven Rogers</option>
            <option value="natasha">Natasha Romanova</option>

        </select>
    </span>
    <!--

        For the sake of simplicity, I used jQuery here.
        Today it's easy to do the same without it, now
        that we have querySelector(), closest(), etc.

    -->
</div>
```

#### A live example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7ac9us70/1052/

*Note 1: Sorry for the gradients & all fancy stuff, no they're not necessary, yes I'm showing off, I know, hashtag onlyhuman, hashtag notproud.*

*Note 2: Those `<optgroup>` tags don't encapsulate the options belonging under them as they normally should; this is intentional. It's better for the styling  (the well-mannered way would be a lot less stylable), and yes this is painless and works in every browser.*

Comment: That's amazing! Do you know why size=15 is required?

Comment: It doesn't have to be 15, what matters is that it has a size - that's what makes it render as a listbox, not a single-line field with a button.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, should've been clearer. What is it about the size attribute that makes it render as a listbox? Is this documented anywhere? Is it a CSS bug? (which means it might be fixed in the future and things relying on it would break). Is it only the size attribute, or will some other attribute (width or height etc) also work? (I can probably easily find out the answer to that last one myself by playing with the fiddle)

Comment: No, it's a well-documented feature of SELECT and it will definitely not go away. I don't know why the guys implemented it like this - size means how high the list should be when it's shown but merely the presence of "size" makes it shown by default. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 4):

Tell the option element to be 13pt

```
select option{
    font-size: 13pt;
}
```

and then the *first* option element to be 7pt

```
select option:first-child {
    font-size: 7pt;
}
```

Running demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VggvD/1/

Comment: It doesn't work on Google Chrome

Comment: You can't do it in Google Chrome (AFAIK)

Comment: @Atropo I think it may not be a bug, but a wanted decision, probably to prevent users writing ugly stuff: let's think to an select with each element of a different height / font, it would be a nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/VggvD/2/

CSS add your code

```
.select_join option{
    font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle shows that this does not work...

Comment: thanks, it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle,

i just edited the above fiddle, its working

http://jsfiddle.net/narensrinivasans/FpNxn/1/

```
.selectDefault, .selectDiv option
{
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: please explain also this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select[value="value"]{
   background-color: red;
   padding: 3px;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: please add some description to your answer why the OP should use this and what is the problem in the OP code