# add css rules to option within a select

Tags: javascript, html, css

once again i need a little help

i got this  that need to have a color of white,
an then the option that is within this select i wanna make a rule that the front color is black.

```
<select name="example_length" aria-controls="example" class=""><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select>
```

i can't give the option a id, curse this is rende by a javascript.

so do anyone know how to make something like select#option color:black or something like that?

once again thx a bunch for your time.

Comment: please try to use correct grammar

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419957/css-style-on-select-option

Comment: @frieder I'm sry, Never been good at it, I will try to get better.

Comment: @mulla.azzi this is just what i need, thx- wanna throw a answer?

Comment: Glad it helped you.... I have marked it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select option{color:#000000 !important}
```

Comment: Your answer has appeared in the low quality posts queue. Please attach an explanation as to how this works and addresses the OPs question.