# Apply CSS to HTML select tag

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I use below name or id of the select tag in order to apply css to it?

```
<div class="span5">
  <select name="fields[abc][]" id="fields[abc]" style="width: 300px;" size="7" multiple="true">
    <option title="abc" value="abc">abc</option>
    <option title="Other" value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This didn't work:

```
select[name=fields[abc][]] {    
  background-color: yellow !important;;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 550px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbbvb40a/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [css style on select option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419957/css-style-on-select-option)

Comment: @H2ONOCK.. not a dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the attribute value inside double quotes:

```
select[name="fields[abc][]"] {
}
```

Demo:

```css
select[name="fields[abc][]"] {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<select name="fields[abc][]" id="fields[abc]" style="width: 300px;" size="7" multiple="multiple">
  <option title="abc" value="abc">abc</option>
  <option title="Other" value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Though this is a nice answer, still i wish I could use doubleQuotes as a part of my name attribute

Comment: @NaeemShaikh If you want to have double quotes in the name, use single quotes around it. Or, escape the quote with a backslash in the CSS.

Comment: if I want both written`'` and `"` consecutively for n number of times... Just kidding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is incorrect. Change your CSS to:

```
option[title='abc'] {    
    background-color: yellow !important;;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 550px;
}
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
option[title='abc'] {    
  background-color: yellow !important;;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  min-height: 550px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="span5">
    <select name="fields[abc][]" id="fields[abc]" style="width: 300px;" size="7" multiple="true">
      <option title="abc" value="abc">abc</option>
      <option title="Other" value="Other">Other </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/cbbvb40a/2/)

---

*Readup:* [Selectors | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: Sorry, but why are you applying the styles to the `option` elements, rather than the `select` as the OP wanted? Your resulting `select` is now a lot higher than the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

You have got `[` and `]` in your name attribute,not a very good idea, but of-course you can use them, you just need to escape them  in css

**working fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/cbbvb40a/1/

```
select[name=fields\[abc\]\[\]] {    
    background-color: yellow !important;;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 550px;
}
```

You can use all the special characters in css this way, here you can find out
Read https://mothereff.in/css-escapes

Comment: In PHP, square brackets inside field names instruct PHP to create an array of values.

Comment: well the question does not belong to php, even if it is just write the css outside in a separate file :), and this solution will also let you any special character be there as attribute value.

Comment: I was referring to the _not a very good idea_ part of your answer. At times, they are required.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different solutions. In your specific example, simply writing

```
select {
```

for a selector will do.

Or if you need to be more specific,

```
div.span5 > select {
```

Another is to escape the square brackets:

```
select[name=fields\[abc\]\[\]] {
```

or put the name in quotes

```
select[name='fields[abc][]'] {
```

or target the id, also with the escaped brackets

```css
#fields\[abc\] {
```

Edit:
Another alternative, for when you are really desperate, is to continue what you already started in the original code, and to use an inline `style` attribute for the whole thing. That way, you won't have to target anything with a stylesheet.

Comment: this is just a copy paste from two of the answers before

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Most answers weren't there when I wrote this!

Comment: I understand.. thats why there is no downvote from me ;)

Comment: @NaeemShaikh If my answer would have been completely superfluous, I'd delete it. But it also shows how to be specific without targeting the name, so I'll leave this up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs),

> Attribute values must be identifiers or strings.

However, `fields[abc][]`

- is not an string, because it has no quotes:

  > Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes.
- is not an [identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), because it contains `[` and `]`:

  > *identifiers* can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the
  >   underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a
  >   hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped
  >   characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next
  >   item).

To fix it, you can

- Use a string: `"fields[abc][]"` or `'fields[abc][]'`.

  ```css
  select[name="fields[abc][]"] {    
      background-color: yellow !important;;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      min-height: 550px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="span5">
    <select name="fields[abc][]" id="fields[abc]" style="width: 300px;" size="7" multiple="true">
      <option title="abc" value="abc">abc</option>
      <option title="Other" value="Other">Other </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ```
- Use a valid identifier, escaping necessary characters

  > Backslash escapes allow authors to refer to characters they cannot
  >   easily put in a document. In this case, the backslash is followed by
  >   at most six hexadecimal digits (0..9A..F), which stand for the ISO
  >   10646 ([[ISO10646]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-ISO10646)) character with that number, which must not be zero.
  >   (It is undefined in CSS 2.1 what happens if a style sheet does contain
  >   a character with Unicode codepoint zero.) If a character in the range
  >   [0-9a-fA-F] follows the hexadecimal number, the end of the number
  >   needs to be made clear. There are two ways to do that:
  >
  > - with a space (or other white space character): "\26 B" ("&B"). In this case, user agents should treat a "CR/LF" pair (U+000D/U+000A) as
  >     a single white space character.
  > - by providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits: "\000026B" ("&B")

  Then,

  - Escape `[` with `\[`, `\5b`, or `\00005b`
  - Escape `]` with `\]`, `\5d`, or `\00005d`

  For example, `fields\[abc\00005d\5b \]`.

  ```css
  select[name=fields\[abc\00005d\5b \]] {    
      background-color: yellow !important;;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      min-height: 550px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="span5">
    <select name="fields[abc][]" id="fields[abc]" style="width: 300px;" size="7" multiple="true">
      <option title="abc" value="abc">abc</option>
      <option title="Other" value="Other">Other </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ```