# How to change color of the select list's first option

Tags: html, css

I couldn't make the selected drop down list's first option color. When we apply color for 'select', all options are getting change. How to change only the first option?

My Code:

```css
#step3-drpdwn {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    height: 34px;
    color: #ccc;
}
#step3-drpdwn>option:not(:first-child) {
    color: #000;
}
#step3-drpdwn>option:first-hand {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<select class="btn btn-md" id="step3-drpdwn">
 <option disabled selected>
  Your Designation or Role in the Company
 </option>
 <option>
  Chairman
 </option>
 <option>
  President
 </option>
 <option>
  CEO
 </option>
 <option>
  Director
 </option>
 <option>
  Proprietor
 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You will not be able to style select options (colors especially) with CSS reliably in all browsers. Use custom select if you really need it.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your problem...the selected item is grey and all others still black...this is not what you want?

Comment: This might help --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/37773973/5561605

Comment: @ElmerDantas - Hi Elmer Dantas, Here the first option is in gray color and when i choose the other options that is also comes in gray color but thats not expected. I want the first option(Your Designation or Role in the Company) should be gray color and if i select the other options those should be in black color.

Comment: aaahhhh...now I understand. Have you got the answer you need?

Comment: @ElmerDantas - No Elmer Dantas, I didn't get yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By what I've understood of your comment, I think that is what you want
**HTML**

```
 <select class="btn btn-md" id="step3-drpdwn" onchange="setColor(this);">
        <option disabled selected>
            Your Designation or Role in the Company
        </option>
        <option>
            Chairman
        </option>
        <option>
            President
        </option>
        <option>
            CEO
        </option>
        <option>
            Director
        </option>
        <option>
            Proprietor
        </option>
    </select>
```

and **JS**

```
function setColor(dropdown){
    dropdown.style.color = "black";
};
```

or if you are using **JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#step3-drpdwn").on("change", function(){
        $(this).css("color", "#000");
    });
});
```

Here's Fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/qyLgorm8/1/  (uncomment the HTML/JS to see working with pure JS)

Hope it helps

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted :) Thank you so much:)

Comment: @Pkprabu glad to help! \o/

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS below:

```css
select#step3-drpdwn option:first-child{
  background: #ccc;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nisse Engstrom. But, This is not what i expect. When select the first-child, It should be in gray color and when i select the other child's, Those should be in black color.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. Try this:

```
$('#step3-drpdwn').change(function () {
    $('#step3-drpdwn').css("background", $("select option:selected").css("red"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Saugat Bhattarai. But, Its not working for me.