# Why we can't style option of dropdown using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-select

In Css we can genrally style all elements but I noticed that we can not style `option` element of a select using CSS. As far as I know Option is child element of `select` then what is possible causes that it don't let you style this element?

I've had reffered various answers on stackoverflow stating that **You just can't style option.** but I want to know exact reason behind it.

I've had reffered [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select) which says that option tag is rendered by OS and not by html. If so then why we need to specify `option` ? why it don't automattically render options.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) is another link which shows how to style Select tag. But i want to know that why we can't style `option`? I don't want to know how to style `select` tag using CSS.

Comment: Chiraj, did you really check for answers to this already answered question.  There are tonnes of questions and references that we cannot style the `option` and why.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I don't want to know how to style it. I want to know why we can't style it.

Comment: @DeepakYadav yes, I did it. But there is not even a single satisfying answer as everyone is stating that it's rendered by OS. I want to know detailed answer.

Comment: @DeepakYadav I've already stated that question in my post and I stated it too that it is saying that option is rendered by OS. But I want detailed answer on it. I'm not satisfied by that single statement. Why it's rendered by OS what is reason behind that.? So please don't get me wrong. I've had already reffered all those questions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot style the `option` element because it is rendered by the OS, not HTML. That is why it can't be styled via CSS.

You can of course use some plug-in that replaces `select` with regular HTML elements that can be styled.

Comment: That answer is already given in the question itself. The author said he wants to dig deeper into that.

Comment: @RobertKusznier I provided this answer before the original question was edited (which you can check by comparing the timestamps). Since I do not get notified of such updates, I have never seen the updated question. As per why you cannot style it: the browser decides what to do with it, and that is it. That is how it is implemented. You should ask the developers of the browsers why it is like that.

Answer (score -1):

There a duplicate method for this... its correct dropdown not accept the styling so you can make the thing which look like dropdown and give styling to that thing..
Here is the link of this explaination check Answer7

[css style on select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419957/css-style-on-select-option)