# selected option colour mozilla

Tags: css, firefox, html-select, mozilla

Is there any way to set the text colour of a selected option in mozilla?

https://jsfiddle.net/36sk6wd0/9/

```
<option selected>blue?</option>
```

You can change the background using a linear gradient, but is there some hack to change the colour as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we can't style option of dropdown using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406185/why-we-cant-style-option-of-dropdown-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

use this link. i hope it's very helpful to you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#changeColor", function() {
    $("option").removeClass("change_color");
    $("#changeColor :selected").addClass("change_color")
  })
})
```

```css
.change_color{
  color:green;
  background-color:yellow;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="changeColor">
  <option>red</option>
  <option>red</option>
  <option>red</option>
</select>
```