# Changing combobox design

Tags: html, css

I have tried changing border color and background in css of the combobox but it's not working:

I have this **HTML** code:

```
<select class = "form-control" style = "border:2px solid white;background:skyblue">
   <option value = "newest"> Newest </option>
   <option value = "oldest"> Oldest </option>
</select>
```

I just simply want to:

1. Remove combobox border
2. Remove the arrow of the combobox
3. Set the background of combobox to skyblue.

I'm sorry if I could not attach any picture for SO requires me to have atleast 10 repu for me to post picture. Please help me with this one. Thanks

**UPDATE:**
 I also tried the `btn-info` in bootstrap but still doesn't work..

Comment: just add as link / share url of image, i ll attach the image for you..

Comment: I have this image saved in my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118491/style-select-option-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

get [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611482/change-color-and-appearance-of-drop-down-arrow)

```css
.styleSelect select {
  background: transparent;
  width: 168px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 34px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: #000;
}

.styleSelect {
  width: 140px;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background:skyblue
  
}
```

```html
<div class="styleSelect">
  <select class="units">
    <option value="Metres">Newest</option>
    <option value="Feet">Feet</option>
    <option value="Fathoms">Oldest</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to this one, it really worked fine now :)

Comment: Sorry can't upvote, due to lack of repu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Done.
2. You can do this, in `webkit` browsers only.
3. Done.

If you want to style your combobox better, you have to write some code or useing a plugin like: [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
  border:0;
  background:skyblue;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for this one also :)

Comment: Sorry can't upvote, due to lack of repu.